# Atributo de sessão do Spring não é mostrado na JSP via JSTL

Tags: java, mvc, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Tenho uma classe Credencial que uso para armazenar informações do usuário em sessão (está anotada com @SessionScope e @Component). Quando eu dou um print em algum atributo dessa classe, aparece normalmente, mas se tento usar ela em uma jsp usando JSTL, o atributo de sessão não é encontrado. Qual o jeito correto de configurar esse atributo de sessão?

**Classe Credencial**

```
@SessionScope
@Component
public class Credencial implements Serializable{

    private String codigoFuncional;

    private String nome;

    private int juncao; 

    private String nomeJuncao;

    private boolean ativo;

    private List<Perfil> perfil;

    private boolean primeiroAcesso;

    //construtor e getters & setters

}
```

**Classe controller**
    ```java
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public class CredencialController {

````
    @Autowired
    private Credencial credencial;

    @PostMapping(value="/validarLogin/")
    public RedirectView efetuarLogin(RedirectAttributes atributos, @Valid @ModelAttribute("credencialDto") CredencialDTO credencialDto, BindingResult resultado, ModelMap modelo){
        System.out.println(credencial.getCodigoFuncional()); //essa linha funciona

    }
  ```
````

Mas quando coloco a seguinte linha na JSP, parece que não encontra o atributo.

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.credencial}" />
```

Está faltando alguma configuração para funcionar? o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, como minha aplicação estava usando a configuração do Spring via java e não XML, precisava colocar uma linha na configuração do ViewResolver:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true); //Essa linha

    return resolver;
}
```